# No data submitted from a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a simple HTML form containing just one field. When I press submit some PHP code that I have written gets called and outputs text that would include submitted data if everything was working. But no submitted text gets printed by the PHP. The form has been created on a Godaddy HTML page and the form is as follows:

```
  <FORM BORDER="1" action="http://www.bestpro.com.au/wordpress/PHB_action.php"
    method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    eenctype="multipart/form-data" name="PHBForm" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"
    ienctype="text/plain">
      <TABLE>
        <TR>
          <TD>First name:</TD><TD><INPUT type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></TD>
          <TD></TD><TD></TD>
          <TD> </TD><TD> </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD> </TD><TD> </TD>
          <TD> </TD><TD></TD>
          <TD> </TD><TD><input type="submit" value="Submit"></TD>
      </TABLE>
    </FORM>
```

The PHP code output starts as follows:

```
   This is where we end up.



   Using `$_POST["firstname"]` which outputs nothing.
   Using `htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"])` which also outputs nothing.
```

Question:
The PHP output doesn't include the value that I entered into the field.
Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: Can you give a sample line of code?

Comment: Could you add some code please???

Comment: Can you add the PHB_action.php code?

Comment: I think that's something with your server, because if I try to use a different URL it's working: [your domain - http://www.bestpro.com.au/wordpress/PHB_action.php](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9LlP.png) vs [google domain - http://www.google.com/PHB_action.php](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFP1E.png). See this [bin](http://jsbin.com/poroya/edit?html,js)

Comment: Mosh, Thank you. I think that you are probably correct. But I have tried http://www.google.com/PHB_action.php but I could not find it. Is that URL correct?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong here, so I can only assume it is something wrong with how you output it on your **PHB_action.php** page.

You say that you're placing `$_POST['firstname']` on your page, but have you actually made sure to `echo` or `print` it to the page?

You can do this like so:

```
echo $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // notice the echo placed before
```

or

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
print("$firstname");
```

**EDIT:**

I've notice you have put your post data inside of single quotation marks when echoing out to your page.

You must concatenate on your data rather than putting them inside of single quotes when echoing, like so:

```
echo 'Using' . $_POST['firstname']; // notice the dot in between the string and the post data.
```

Either that, or you have not installed PHP correctly (or at all) onto your server.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Caelan. Thanks for your comments. The following is some of my PHP:     <HTML>
This is where we end up.<BR>
<!-- Neither enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" nor enctype="multipart/form-data" work -->
<!--?php
    $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true); ?--><BR><!--
    The above two lines have no effect. --><BR><!--?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?--><BR><?php
    echo 'Using $_POST["firstname"] '.$_POST["firstname"].' which outputs nothing.';  ?><BR><?php
    echo 'Using htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]) '...

Answer (score 0):

So, this is pretty straight forward and I have written it up and will explain each bit as i go.

The PHP you need for this is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['firstName'];
    if (!empty($fname))
    {
        echo "hello $fname";
    } else {
        echo "Please supply your first name.";
    }
}
?>
```

$_POST['send'] is the name of your submit button, this will be the trigger for your PHP to initiate and run through the rest of the code.

`$fname = $_POST['firstName']`
This is just where I prefer to store the $_POST as a variable in the event you are going to re use it again it saves time writing the entire thing.

`if(!empty)`

if the username isn't empty (!empty meaning not empty) then perform the echo of $fname. however if it comes back as empty it will echo the `else echo "please supply...`;

Now for the form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="send"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Just a straight forward form with a blank action on mine (I prefer to keep the PHP within the same file however I normally relay it back to a Class within a different file.

Each form input (First Name / Submit) must have a name="" value otherwise the PHP cannot read it and run with it.

I hope this makes sense and isn't too puzzling :)

Answer (score -1):

Your input field should be inside  tag and method should be post. Like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <Form method=post>
            <input id=mytextfield name=mytextfield type=text />
            <input type=submit value=Submit />
        </Form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I saw. Either my page didn't refresh or I missed to see it.

Comment: I used your form and pressed submit. It took me to the url http://bestpro.com.au/wordpress/PHB_action.php and produced big dump. In the dump I see ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET".

Comment: Is the file PHB_action.php created by you? When I post the data to the url you have given I see exactly the same message you mentioned. If you have created the php file please post the content of the php file and not the output.

Comment: Can you try uploading a php file lets call it test.php? Inside that use code <? echo $_POST['firstname']; ?> and point the url in the form to http://www.bestpro.com.au/wordpress/test.php

Comment: Hi "The Shooter". Thank you for your comment. However, if I copy the PHP that already exists into test.php and put it on the bestpro.com.au server it won't be much different to what is already there. As such I have edited the PHP and included it in a HTML file as follows: http://bestpro.com.au/wordpress/TheShooter.html  This is my second attempt at responding to you. When I used <CTRL>K to try to format the PHP code better on my first attempt Stack Overflow just cancelled my message.

Comment: Hi "Option". Thanks for your response. I included your PHP with a few modifications and got a message from the else that I added to your first "if" that says " Submit doesn't exist". (My Submit button has the value "Submit".)

Comment: The link you posted bestpro.com.au/wordpress/TheShooter.html doesn't load. Also you don't need to copy existing php code into test.php. Just have one line of php code <? echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>  in the file. This will demonstrate how actually the php server side is behaving.